# woocommerce событие при смене статуса заказа

Tags: woocommerce, функции

В моем woocommerce  2.4.8  при смене статуса заказа в админке

```
 if ( 'completed' == $order_status && ( 'on-hold' == $order->status || 'completed' == $order->status || 'failed' == $order->status ) ) {

    function my_func();

}
```

должна выполняться некая функция вот никак не пойму где это лучше прописать... в файлах woocommerce  или в functions.php
Если в functions.php, тогда как буде строиться логика???

```
add_action('woocommerce_order_status_completed', 'my_compl');
function my_compl_2() {
..............
 }
```

Хорошо было бы сделать в самих файлах woocommerce чтобы не зависело от шаблонов.

Answer (score 1):

Нашел решение но только по перехвату события через файл `functions.php` 
Ещё раз о задаче при смене Статуса Заказа нужно выводить событие, по сути выполнение своей функции. В `functions.php` вставляем:

```
// Если заказ Выполнен
add_action('woocommerce_order_status_completed', 'my_compl_2');
function my_compl_2( $order_id ) {
    error_log( "Order complete for order $order_id", 0 ); 
}
```

Далее всё просто, меняем в add_action конструкцию на нужную Вам.

- woocommerce_order_status_pending
- woocommerce_order_status_failed
- woocommerce_order_status_on-hold
- woocommerce_order_status_processing
- woocommerce_order_status_completed
- woocommerce_order_status_refunded
- woocommerce_order_status_cancelled

Естественно меняем название своей функции или обращаемся к ней повторно.